# ESLint / Vim (or neovim) workflow

Tags: vim, eslint, neovim

I have used ESLint with Vim and various other plugins like Ale and Prettier. I am now having a lot of difficulty setting things up again. It would be useful for me to know what the ESLint plugin does without any other plugins at all or any other configuration of Vim or neovim.

I am finding the documentation very difficult to follow. I think this is partly because ESLint works in many contexts not just Vim` and also much of what is written assumes other plugins are installed e.g. Ale.

I am guessing that if you are editing a Vim file (perhaps only if it has `.js` extension?) you can then go into normal mode and invoke ESLint (e.g. `:eslint`) and then see any errors in the code indicated.

Comment: Why do you have to set it all up again? What happened to your config? And if you set it up once, you surely can do it twice, don't you? Also, you didn't bother providing any link so no one knows what you are talking about. What eslint plugin? Why an eslint plugin when Vim already comes with a `:help :compiler` for it?

Comment: Your profile: "A mild mannered, patient and tenderly forgiving vimmocent by day and a churlish, grumpy and astutely critical vimquisitor by night." I think I must have caught you at night. Are you sure about the astute bit?

Comment: Does ESLint require other plugins (eg Ale or Syntastic) in order to work with Vim or neovim? That does seem to implied by this webpage: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/integrations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The basics

1. For the sake of simplification, ESLint is best thought of as a standalone command-line linter, **that is not related in any way to Vim or any other text editor/IDE**.
2. The default usage pattern is to execute it in your shell with files as arguments:

   ```
   $ eslint goodfile.js
   (no output)

   $ eslint badfile.js
   (list of errors)
   ```

   It can also be used as filter:

   ```
   $ echo 'console.log(1)' | eslint --stdin
   (list of errors)
   ```
3. It can also be told to fix what it can instead of merely reporting it:

   ```
   $ eslint --fix badfile.js
   ```

### In Vim

Like lots of command-line programs (linters or not), ESLint can be used from Vim in lots of ways.

The simplest is to execute it directly on the current file:

```
:!eslint %
(list of errors)
```

or on the current buffer if it is not written to disk:

```
:w !eslint --stdin
(list of errors)
```

But that method, while informative, is not very useful because the errors disappear as soon as you press `<CR>`.

A much better approach is to use the `:make` command, which populates the quickfix list with the errors reported by the underlying linter or compiler or whatever. In general, it works like this:

1. Tell Vim to use program `foo` for `:make` with `set makeprg=foo`.
2. Tell Vim how to parse the output of `foo` with `set errorformat+=<pattern>`.
3. Do `:make %` to run the current file through `foo`.
4. Do `:cwindow` to show the list of errors reported by `foo`, if any.

In the case of ESLint, if your Vim is recent enough, it should come with what it calls a "compiler script" (that I wrote), which basically does steps #1 and #2 above for you. You can check if you have it with:

```
:compiler eslint
```

If you get an error, consider this as an opportunity to upgrade.

After you have selected a compiler, you can perform steps #3 and #4 above to lint your file, which is, let's be honest, tedious.

From there, you can choose one of three paths:

1. keep doing it like that because it's fine,
2. learn a little more of your editor in order to automatise the whole process,
3. give up on the tinkering and use a third-party plugin.

Path #2 looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/romainl/ce55ce6fdc1659c5fbc0f4224fd6ad29). It is not particularly hard or complicated but I wouldn't recommend to a copy/pasting newbie.

Path #3 involves installing a plugin like ALE, which is throughly documented and has a dedicated issue tracker.

Comment: thanks for that clarification. I have taken path #3 which is working except that I am struggling to understand some configuration issues. One thing I have not got straight in my mind is where the linters themselves ought to be put and where ALE looks for them. I thought that might happen behind the scenes but am not sure about it yet.

Comment: Vim is generic by design: instead of being super tailored for a specific language or stack, it only exposes basic "connectors", so to speak, for integrating specialized external tools. It is those external tools, like ESLint, that do the linting, not ALE or Vim. The whole point of ALE is to make that integration painless but it still lets you handle those external tools on your own. In the case of ESLint, ALE's assumption is that it was either installed locally, as part of the project's dev dependencies, or globally. How to do that is yours to figure out and decide.